# How to solve this error in react native app?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, expo

Now I am trying to make an app in react native and expo.
Yesterday, I got fine but today when I did expo start, I got this error.

> TypeError: undefined is not an object(evaluating 'this._callListeners.bind')

I think this problem is based on react-navigation, expo or other version.

This is my package.json below

```
"dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^9.0.0",
    "expo": "^32.0.0",
    "expo-cli": "^2.11.9",
    "firebase": "^4.12.1",
    "mobx": "^5.8.0",
    "mobx-react": "^5.4.3",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.23.0",
    "react-native-modal": "^7.0.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.1.0",
    "react-navigation": "^3.4.1"
    },
     "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.3.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.3.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.5",
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0",
    "babel-preset-mobx": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^4.0.1",
    "directory": "^0.1.0",
    "eslint": "^5.12.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.12.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.53.0"
},
```

Comment: By searching on google: yarn add react-native-gesture-handler && react-native link

Comment: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/5244 same issue check it out

Answer (score 0):

After my app started showing this error for no apparent reason, I spent hours google searching for solutions to this issue and nothing worked.  Finally I tried doing `expo start -c` because I remembered it mentioned in the [Expo v33 upgrade documentation](https://blog.expo.io/expo-sdk-v33-0-0-is-now-available-52d1c99dfe4c).  My error went away.